# Globally set file writer encoding

Tags: groovy, character-encoding

I have a Groovy application in which I have at least four occurrences of this code (and counting):

```groovy
new File(filePath).withWriter('UTF-8') { out ->
    [...]
}
```

I *feel* there should be a way to specify that I want to write *every* file using UTF-8 without having to specify it by myself.

Can I? How?

Answer (score 1):

you could add a helper (in case no one comes up with a proper answer):

```
def withUtf8Writer = { file, closure -> new File(file).withWriter('UTF-8', closure) }

new File('/tmp/f1').withWriter('UTF-8') { out ->
    out.println 'ẗ' 
}

withUtf8Writer('/tmp/f2') { out ->
    out.println 'ẗ'
}

assert "diff /tmp/f1 /tmp/f2".execute().text == ''
```